# Explode pandas rows based on function applied to each row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe df as follows:

```
Col1    Price   Day
A       16      5
B       12      3
D       5       8
```

I need to apply a function to each row of df:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
def Fn(Price, Day):
  pr = np.arange(Price/2, Price + Price/2, Price/2)
  da = np.arange(Day/2, Day+ Day/2, Day/2)
  return pd.DataFrame({'Price':pr, 'Day':da)
```

I need to achieve the following:

```
Col1    Price   Day
A       8       2.5
A       16      5
B       6       1.5
B       12      3
D       2.5     4
D       5       8
```

In reality with the function `Fn` has something like:

```
pr = np.arange(Price/18, Price + Price/18, Price/18)
da = np.arange(Day/18, Day+ Day/18, Day/18)
```

I am not sure how to proceed with the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution, which:

1. Iterates over the rows of the dataframe with `map`
2. Applies `Fn` in each iteration, getting the corresponding resulting dataframe, which is put into a list.
3. Finally, concatenates all dataframes of the mentioned list into a single dataframe.

```
(pd.concat(map(
    lambda x: pd.concat(
        [pd.Series(x[1]['Col1'], name='Col1'),
         Fn(x[1]['Price'], x[1]['Day'])], axis=1, ignore_index=True),
    df.iterrows()))
 .ffill()
 .set_axis(df.columns, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
  Col1  Price  Day
0    A    8.0  2.5
1    A   16.0  5.0
0    B    6.0  1.5
1    B   12.0  3.0
0    D    2.5  4.0
1    D    5.0  8.0
```

Comment: Will this be faster than applying for loop for each row, storing it in a list and doing pd.concat on the list.

Comment: I do not think it would be faster, as, according to this web-page, `map` is faster than `for` loop: https://www.knowledgehut.com/blog/programming/python-map-list-comprehension. Other web-sites claim likewise.